# Max and Step for a submit validation error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm having a problem to submit data in a form. The thing is I have 2 inputs and 1 of them depends of the other to change its value, i set the new max value with jquery but when I try to submit it says that the new number it's not in the range

```js
$('#ventas_cheque_valor').on('keyup change click', function() {
  //  $('#div_cheque_opciones').removeClass('disabledbutton')
  $('#ventas_efectivo_valor').val(total_final)
  $(this).attr('max', total_final)
  let valor = parseFloat($(this).val())

  if (valor > total_final) {
    toastr.error('Éste valor no debe ser superior a: <strong>' + total_final + '</strong>', {
      timeOut: 5000
    })
    $(this).val(0)
  } else if (valor <= total_final) {
    let nuevo = total_final - valor
    $('#ventas_efectivo_valor').val(parseFloat(nuevo))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ventas_efectivo_valor" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>Efectivo</strong></label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ventas_efectivo_valor" placeholder="Valor" step="0.01">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ventas_cheque_valor" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>Cheque</strong></label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ventas_cheque_valor" placeholder="Valor" step="0.01" min="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer to your question.

Cause my English is not good enough, if I misunderstood your question please tell me.

```js
var total_final = 100; // previously undefined
$('#ventas_efectivo_valor').val(total_final)
$('#ventas_cheque_valor').attr('max', total_final)
  
$('#ventas_cheque_valor').on('keyup change', function() {
//  $('#div_cheque_opciones').removeClass('disabledbutton')
  let valor = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);

  if (valor > total_final) {
    /*toastr.error('Éste valor no debe ser superior a: <strong>' + total_final + '</strong>', {
      timeOut: 5000
    })*/
    $(this).val(0);
  } else if (valor <= total_final) {
    let nuevo = (total_final - valor).toFixed(2);
    $('#ventas_efectivo_valor').val(nuevo);
    $(this).val(valor);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ventas_efectivo_valor" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>Efectivo</strong></label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ventas_efectivo_valor" placeholder="Valor" step="0.01">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ventas_cheque_valor" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>Cheque</strong></label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ventas_cheque_valor" placeholder="Valor" step="0.01" min="0">
  </div>
</div>
```